# Slice unexpectedly slow when `c()` is used to supply multiple row values compared to doing individual slices

Tags: r, dplyr

I do not understand why taking the `slice` with first and last values is 5 times slower than taking the `slice` with first, then last values.

```
library(dplyr)
letters <- c("A", "B", "C")
timestamps <- Sys.time() + 1:1000
integer_sizes <- 1:300

N = 700000

df <- 
    data.frame(letters = sample(letters, N, replace = TRUE),
           sizes = sample(integer_sizes, N, replace = TRUE),
           time = sample(timestamps, N, replace = TRUE),
           price = runif(N),
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
    arrange(letters, sizes, time)

fn_first <- function(){
    df %>%
        group_by(letters, sizes, time) %>%
        slice(1)
}

fn_last <- function(){
    df %>%
        group_by(letters, sizes, time) %>%
        slice(n())
}

fn_combined <- function(){
    df %>%
        group_by(letters, sizes, time) %>%
        slice(c(1, n()))
}
```

gives benchmark results of:

```
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(fn_first(), fn_last(), fn_combined(), times = 5)
Unit: seconds
          expr      min       lq     mean   median        uq       max neval
    fn_first() 1.038021 1.080131 1.130611 1.092370  1.136293  1.306238     5
     fn_last() 1.198582 1.236393 1.282161 1.303314  1.320716  1.351801     5
 fn_combined() 9.817495 9.916474 9.977188 9.955553 10.090996 10.105425     5
```

**EDIT**: It seems like this has something to do with the concatenation operator:

```
fn_c <- function(){
    df %>%
        group_by(letters, sizes, time) %>%
        slice(c(1))
}

fn_no_c <- function(){
    df %>%
        group_by(letters, sizes, time) %>%
        slice(1)
}
```

gives

```
> microbenchmark(fn_c(), fn_no_c(), times = 5)
Unit: seconds
      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
    fn_c() 8.910264 9.119980 9.222461 9.264068 9.377603 9.440387     5
 fn_no_c() 1.068043 1.075615 1.153856 1.154506 1.211585 1.259534     5
```

with

```
> all.equal(fn_c(), fn_no_c())
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Two more stumpers: if you don't include `group_by`, the times are a lot more comparable; and if you use `.[5,]` instead of `slice(5)` (and likewise with `.[c(5),]`), the difference goes away. Perhaps this is a bug in `slice`. (I've found no places where I preferred `slice` over something like `.[1,]` or `do(head,n=1)`, though I'm likely missing good use-cases.)

Comment: i am inclined to think that this is a bug... I wasn't aware you could use `[]` notation when in `group_by`

Comment: Good point ... you can't, but `%>% do(head(., n=1))` (corrected from my previous comment) does work with grouping and is *slightly* faster in my testing.